# How to test payable method in truffle?

Tags: testing, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I'm trying to test smart contract's payable method in truffle framework:

```solidity
contract Contract {
  mapping (address => uint) public balances;

  function myBalance() public view returns(uint) {
    return balances[msg.sender];
  }

  function deposit() external payable {
    balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
  }
}

contract TestContract {

  function testDeposit() external payable {
    Contract c = new Contract();

    c.deposit.value(1);

    Assert.equal(c.myBalance(), 1, "#myBalance() should returns 1");
  }
}
```

After I run `truffle test`, it's fails with `TestEvent(result: <indexed>, message: #myBalance() should returns 1 (Tested: 0, Against: 1))` error. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your test contract has a couple issues. The first is you're not initializing your test contract to hold any ether. Therefore, there are no funds held by the `TestContract` to send to `Contract`. To do this, you need to set an `initialBalance` contract storage variable (see [Testing ether transactions](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-solidity#testing-ether-transactions)).

Second, you're not calling your `deposit` function correctly. To call a function and send ether, the format is `contract.functionName.value(valueInWei)(<parameter list>)`.

Here is the fixed version of `TestContract`:

```
contract TestContract {
  uint public initialBalance = 1 wei;

  function testDeposit() external payable {
    Contract c = new Contract();

    c.deposit.value(1)();

    Assert.equal(c.myBalance(), 1, "#myBalance() should returns 1");
  }
}
```